# Play audio from Assets folder in W10 universal app

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-10, win-universal-app

I have several .wav and .mp3 files in my app under Assets/Audio, and I'm trying to play them when something is tapped in the UI.  I've written the following code (with the file name hardcoded for testing purposes), but when the function is triggered, no sound plays.  If I replace attempting to play from a file to playing an audio stream created by Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer, everything works fine.

```
 private async void SoundItem_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem soundItem = sender as ListViewItem;

        if (soundItem.IsSelected)
        {
            Uri sourceUri = new Uri(String.Format("ms-appx:///Assets/Audio/151Cry.wav", UriKind.Absolute));

            await PlayAudio(sourceUri, soundItem);
        }
        else if (inUsePlayers.ContainsKey(soundItem))
        {
            MediaElement player = inUsePlayers[soundItem];
            player.Stop();
            inUsePlayers.Remove(soundItem);
            players.Enqueue(player);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    private async Task PlayAudio(Uri sourceUri, ListViewItem soundItem)
    {
        MediaElement player = RequestPlayer(soundItem);

        player.Source = sourceUri;
        player.IsLooping = true;

        await player.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            player.Stop();
            player.Play();
        });
    }
```

Here's the location of the file within the tree:

[image]

Aside from dragging the sound files into the project, I've haven't done anything.  Maybe they need to be added to a resource file or copied to the output folder as well?  I expected that something would throw an exception if the item pointed to by the URI didn't exist, but nothing's being thrown, even when I give it a bogus filename.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do following things to play you media element.

1. Your resource files should be set to "**Copy to Output directory**"
   value to "**Copy if newer**" or "**Copy always**". to do this right
   **click your resource file** go to **Properties** and set **Copy to Output directory** value to **Copy always** and **Build action** to
   **content**
2. Your player(MediaElement) should be added somewhere to View xaml
   tree. I do not know your RequestPlayer method is adding
   mediaEelement to view xaml or not. e.g
   layoutRoot.Children.Add(player)
3. You need to register **Player_MediaOpened** event to play your
   audio file. If you call 'play' before player is opened media will
   not play the sound... and if you want that if any thing is happend
   to your player not playing than register **Player_MediaFailed** it
   will give you the reason why it is filed to play.

here is the code.

```
  private async Task PlayAudio(Uri sourceUri, ListViewItem soundItem)
    {
        MediaElement player = RequestPlayer(soundItem);
        player.IsLooping = true;
        player.AutoPlay = false;
        player.MediaOpened += Player_MediaOpened;
        player.MediaFailed += Player_MediaFailed;
        player.Source = sourceUri;
        player.IsLooping = true;
        //Add media element to xaml tree if not added by your RequestPlayer Method..
        this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(player);

    }

    private void Player_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private async void Player_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await player.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            player.Play();
        });
    }
```

Hope this helps...